# Where to start with Binary Search Tree?

Tags: binary-search-tree

By my understanding when completing a binary search you start with the middle value and complete a divide and conquer algorithm upon it until you find the correct value.

However when I have looked at Binary Search Trees it was my understanding that this is completed in the same way with the initial node being the middle value, however I have seen examples of unsorted lists starting with first node being the first value in the array.

Which method is correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you start with the middle node, then examine the left and right halves.

Divide and conquer algorithms approach the problem recursively by breaking the original problem into sub-problems of smaller size. The problem will be reduced down until it is small enough to be solved in a straightforward manner.

It the case of the Binary Search Tree, the algorithm takes the middle node, then recursively solves the right and left sub-problems.

```
BinarySearch(Array arr, value)
    return BinarySearchAux(arr, value, 0, arr.length)

BinarySearch(Array arr, value, start, end)
    if start >= end
        return value == arr[start]
    mid = floor((end - start) / 2)
    if value == arr[mid]
        return true
    return 
        BinarySearchAux(arr, value, start, mid-1) || 
        BinarySearchAux(arr, value, mid+1, end)
```

Comment: How would you eve get an unbalanced one sided tree if always starting with middle value?